# Using cardStyleInterpolators and transitionSpec throwing "No overload matches this call error" in Typescript React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v6

I have been trying to implement animations using  cardStyleInterpolators and transitionSpec. But using these props in screenOptions and options of the stack screen throwing **No overload matches this call error**. I'm using Typescript and react navigation v6, all other props are working except these.

```
import React from "react";
import { Image } from "react-native";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import {
  createNativeStackNavigator,
  NativeStackScreenProps,
  NativeStackNavigationOptions,
  NativeStackNavigationEventMap,
} from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import {
  NavigationContainer,
  RouteProp,
  RouteConfig,
  StackNavigationState,
} from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer";
import { navigationRef } from "./RootNavigation";
import Route from "./route";
import MainScreen from "src/screen/main-screen";
import Profile from "src/screen/Profile";


type RootStackParamList = {
  [Route.welcome]: undefined;
  [Route.phoneLogin]: {
    isOrderScreen?: boolean;
  };
  [Route.mainScreen]: {
    fromHome?: any;
  };
  [Route.filterSearch]: undefined;
  [Route.searchResult1]: undefined;
  [Route.productPage]: {
    productData?: SearchProductItemI;
  };
  [Route.fleetPayment]: undefined;
  [Route.trackorder]: undefined;
  [Route.mycart]: undefined;
  [Route.picklocation]: undefined;
  [Route.otpVerify]: {
    phoneNumber?: string | undefined;
    isOrderScreen?: boolean;
    deliveryFleet?: string | undefined | boolean;
    userId?: string | undefined;
    roleId?: string | undefined;
    staticOtp?: any;
  };
  [Route.searchproduct]: {
    searchname?: any;
    isSearch?: boolean;
    storeCategoryName?: any;
  };

  [Route.ordersummary]: {
    orderId?: string;
  };
  [Route.fleetsummary]: undefined;
  [Route.producttracking]: undefined;

  [Route.newTrackOrder]: any;

  [Route.drawerorder]: undefined;
  [Route.drawermylocation]: undefined;
  [Route.drawerdeliveryfleets]: undefined;
  [Route.profile]: undefined;
  [Route.trackrider]: undefined;
  [Route.orderformerchant]: undefined;
  [Route.orderformerchanttwo]: undefined;
  [Route.orderPayment]: any;
  [Route.myorderdetails]: any;
  [Route.storepage]: any;
  [Route.storeBasedOnCategory]: any;
  [Route.seeAllScreen]: any;
  [Route.paymentTip]: any;
  [Route.notification]: any;
  [Route.addressform]: any;
  [Route.fleetform]: any;
  [Route.googlesearch]: any;
  [Route.welcomescreen]: any;
  [Route.locationfetch]: any;
  [Route.productBottomPage]: any;
  [Route.subcategoryscreen]: any;
  // [Route.home]: undefined;
};

declare global {
  namespace ReactNavigation {
    interface RootParamList extends RootStackParamList {}
  }
}

export type RootRouteProps<RouteName extends keyof RootStackParamList> =
  RouteProp<RootStackParamList, RouteName>;

export type RootStackScreenProps<Screen extends keyof RootStackParamList> =
  NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, Screen>;

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function CommonStacks() {
  const { isLoggedIn } = useSelector((state: any) => state.isLoggedIn);
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName={Route.welcomescreen}
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
        
      }}
    >
      <Stack.Screen component={MainScreen} name={Route.mainScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen component={Profile} name={Route.profile} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
   )
}
```

this is the code, I have been using.

Answer (score 0):

I was using native stacks and it doesn't have these props, instead you could use **animation** option to apply different predefined animations moving to other screens in the stack. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/native-stack-navigator/#animation